# match a field and return value when matching between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Fields where formula to get the staff hourly rate will be are:

[image]

File containing the data is:

[image]

I've tried a combination VLOOKUP and LOOKUP (for between dates) but can't get something that works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version do you have?  Please show the formula you have tried/

Comment: Not all dates in your screenshot are allogned. Sure they not text looking like dates?

Comment: How many different rates could a worker have?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use **Index and Match** formulas to make this work. However, before doing so, I think you should first create another column where you keep your contract time periods. Call it "adjusted end date", and populate today's date if the end date is empty.

So, if end date is in column G, then adjusted end could be in column H and have this formula:

```
    =IF(G2="",TODAY(),G2)
```

So, your contract data has columns of User, Start Date, End Date, Adjusted End Date and Rate.

Next, you'll want to create an array formula when calculating the rate for the user workdate. So, column A is user, Column B is workdate, and column c is rate. This formula will go into column C:

```
    =INDEX(I$2:I$19999,MATCH(1,IF(B2>=F$2:F$9999,IF(B2<=H$2:H$9999,IF(A2=$E$2:$E$9999,1))),0))
```

Then, to make it an array formula, simultaneously press **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**. Drag the formula down. This formula looks at the workdate and user, and finds the appropriate rate line. We previously created that pseudo-end-date to make this formula work w/out too much fuss when the end date is null.

Final result looks like this:

[image: excel pic]

Answer (score 0):

I used a table and structured references, although you can change it to regular addressing if you must.

I named the hourly rate table `tblHrly`

```
C2: =MAX(tblHrly[RATE]*(A2=tblHrly[USERNAME])*(B2>=tblHrly[START_DATE])*(B2<=IF(tblHrly[END_DATE]=0,TODAY(),tblHrly[END_DATE])))
```

Depending on your version of Excel, you may be able to enter this normally, or you may have to enter it as an array formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`

[image]

***Note:** You could also construct this table using `Power Query`, but, without formulas, you'd have to update the query each time something changed.  If you have a huge table of hourly rate data, it might or might not be faster.*